# How do I use "after ms script" in TCL?

Tags: timeout, tcl

I'm trying to figure out how to use "after" in TCL version 8.6.0.  Here's what I attempted:

```
proc async {} {
    set state waiting
    puts "pre-timeout $state"
    set id [after 1000 {set state timeout}]
    puts "wait-timeout $state"
    after 2000
    puts "post-timeout $state"
}
async
```

Output:

```
pre-timeout waiting
wait-timeout waiting
post-timeout waiting
```

Expected output:

```
pre-timeout waiting
wait-timeout waiting
post-timeout timeout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusing part about the after command is that it has two very distinct forms. If you say

```
after 2000
```

then execution stops for 2000 ms and then resumes at the next command.

If you say

```
after 1000 {set ::state timeout}
```

then the set command is executed after 1000 ms **but you must enter the event loop**. The way to enter the event loop is

```
vwait ::state
```

The final thing to remember is that the after script executes at the global level, outside of any procedure. Try the following code:

```
proc async {} {
    set ::state waiting
    puts "pre-timeout $::state"
    set id [after 1000 {set ::state timeout}]
    puts "wait-timeout $::state"
    vwait ::state
    puts "post-timeout $::state"
}
async
```

Comment: It's possible to make things _very_ confusing by putting `vwait` in a procedure. If you've got Tcl 8.6, using [`coroutine`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/coroutine.htm) and the [related Tcllib package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/coroutine/tcllib_coroutine.html) can greatly simplify things.

Comment: Yeah, what Donal said.If you are considering a design that is event driven and haven't undertaken one before, it is a different execution model and takes a different mindset to design to it. It is very powerful but just not the design style most people are first taught.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize I had to "enter the event loop".

Answer (score 1):

Use vwait forever to keep the program running and then exit when you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc async {countdown} {
        puts $countdown
        incr countdown -1
        if {$countdown > 0} {
                after 1000 "async $countdown"
        } else {
                after 1000 {puts Blastoff!; exit}
        }
}

async 5

# Don't exit the program and let async requests
# finish.
vwait forever
```

Output:

```
./async.tcl
5
4
3
2
1
Blastoff!
```